# Rendering error in constraint layout

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0, android-constraintlayout

So tbh I am a bit of a noob when it comes to android programming. Started an app development yesterday after a long hiatus. I have worked with Android Studio and Relative / Linear layout in the past but with the new constraint layout I am having rendering issues. It just refuses to render the text view. I have tried to search and tried every possible fix for the same. I have attached a screenshot of the same

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try rebuilding your project as follows; *Build >> Rebuild* Project. Somethings the you can't see the design until you've made a successful build.

Also, check that you have included this in your build.grade dependencies

```
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
```